# How can I compare an integer to the value I get from an enum?

Tags: c#

I have the following method and enum:

```
public int GetRowType(string pk) 
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(pk.Substring(2, 2));
    }


public enum CONTENT {
    Menu = 0,
    Article = 1,
    FavoritesList = 2,
    ContentBlock = 3,
    Topic = 6,
    List = 7
};
```

Here I am trying to check if the result of my method is equal to the value of the enum but I am getting an error:

```
GetRowType(content) == CONTENT.Topic
```

Can someone give me some advice on what I am doing wrong?

```
Gives me an error: Error    2   
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Storage.Constants.CONTENT'
```

Comment: Your question has already been answered, but I might note that all uppercase "CONTENT" is very old school, and not up to date with the standards of naming in C# :)

Comment: The whole idea, IIRC, with `enum`s is that you work with them rather than with integers.  Why do you need to go to integers?

Comment: @caesay - Someone else suggested uppercase for me. What would you suggest for the naming of the enum? I already have a Content Class so I was thinking CONTENT would be appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: the correct name would just be "Content" (Pascal case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea is to work with the enum directly. so to fix up your method and return a enum instead of an integer:

```
public CONTENT GetRowType(string pk) 
{
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(pk.Substring(2, 2));
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CONTENT), temp)) 
    { 
        return (CONTENT)temp;
    }
    else throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks very good. Quick question. What would you suggest as a naming standard for CONTENT?

Comment: Content (as it is a enum, it follows Pascal case "PascalCase" naming rules). Variables follow camel case, which would be "camelCase"

Comment: But the problem is I already have a class called Content. Then maybe ContentRowType but that seems rather long :-(

Comment: "ContentType" would be appropriate. You really should never use different things and use casing to separate them. For example, if you had a "CONTENT", "Content", and "content" type, that could get very confusing. Side on more descriptive class names as to be less confusing for yourself and anyone else later on.

Answer (score 6):

Just cast enum value to int, explicitly

```
GetRowType(content) == (int)CONTENT.Topic
```

Comment: Is there another way I could do it by making the GetRowType return a CONTENT?

Comment: I was think of doing that in the method. Can I just cast with (CONTENT)  inside and before return?

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly cast your enum to an int:

```
(int)CONTENT.Topic
```

Having said that it might make more sense for your method to return an enum (this time explicitly casting your int to the enum within the method)

Comment: I was thinking same with the method return. But not sure how I could implement that.